# Accessing model from FileSystemStorage

Tags: python, django

I have custom FileSystemStorage.
The idea is to pass optional filename parameter.
My custome storge code:

```
class SalesMapFileStores(FileSystemStorage):
    def __init__(self, location=None, base_url=None, filename=None):
        if filename:
            self.filename = filename
        super(SalesMapFileStores, self).__init__(location=location, base_url=base_url)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name

    def get_valid_name(self, name):
        if self.filename:
            return self.filename
        return name

    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return super(SalesMapFileStores, self)._save(name, conten
```

What i whant is to pass this filename parameter from model.
Somethin like this:

```
class SalesMapImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name='Filename')
    image = SalesMapImageField(upload_to='SalesMap/Test', storage=SalesMapFileStores(filename=name), verbose_name='Test Image',
                               content_types=('image/jpeg', 'image/png'))
```

But in this case, Django passes as a parameter itself model.CharField (it's obvious :)).
The question is: **how can I get access to my model instance from Storage?**
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a bit crazy idea but you can try to override the assignment to that field in that class so the `SalesMapFileStores` instance always keep in sync with the `name` field like this:

```
class SalesMapImage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name='Filename')
    image = SalesMapImageField(upload_to='SalesMap/Test', storage=SalesMapFileStores(), verbose_name='Test Image',
                               content_types=('image/jpeg', 'image/png'))

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        self.__dict__[key]=value
        if key=='name':
            self.image.storage.filename = value
```

And the general idea is to hook the assignment of the value to the update of the filename field.

This is supposing that you don't want to update it manually from within your view. Because it wouldn't take much effort to do `model_instance.storage.filename = self.name` or even add a method to your custom storage class to update the filename.

**UPDATE:** Heads up for the `storage=SalesMapFileStores()`. There you are passing a instance of `SalesMapFileStores`. Not the class, so it might be possible you'll be using the same instace for storing all files and this my bring conflicts with `filename`. You can try it like this: `storage=SalesMapFileStores`

Hope this helps!